# AWS S3 Bucket upload all only zip files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload all my zip files in folder to my s3 bucket using this command

```
aws s3 cp recursive s3://<bucket-name>/%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% --
recursive --include="*.zip" --exclude="*" --exclude="*/*/*"
```

the exclude only works in files but not in directory so my all my directory with zip files inside still uploading. Is there a way to upload only the zip files and exclude all kinds of other files and directories without specifying the name of directory/files.

Comment: Are you saying that it is working OK for the specified directory, but you want it to **not* copy anything in sub-directories?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

> When there are multiple filters, the rule is the filters that appear later in the command take precedence over filters that appear earlier in the command.

---

Had a similar issue, turns out you need to put `exclude="*"` first.

```
aws s3 cp recursive s3://<bucket-name>/%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% --
recursive --exclude="*" --exclude="*/*/*" --include="*.zip" 

Should work
```